# Global Variable Reset not working in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, global-variables, webapp2

I am calling a web crawling function from a handler in GAE and it retrieves a few images and then displays them.  It works just fine on the first call but then the next time it displays all the same images and the crawler starts up from where the last one left off.  I think it is a problem with my global variables not being reset correctly.

Everytime I redeploy the app it does it correctly the first time but then the problem begins.

Here is my code please let me know if you need me to clarify it but I think it should make sense.

Here is the scraper function

```
visited_pages = []
visit_queue = deque([])
collected_pages = []
collected_pics = []
count = 0
pic_count = 0

def scrape_pages(url, root_url, keywords=[], recurse=True):
    #variables
    max_count = 16
    pic_num = 100

    global count
    global pic_count
    global collected_pics
    global collected_pages

    print 'the keywords and url are'
    print keywords
    print url

    #this is all of the links that have been scraped
    the_links = []

    soup = soupify_url(url)

    #only add new pages onto the queue if the recursion argument is true    
    if recurse:
        #find all the links on the page
        try:
            for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
                the_links.append(tag.get('href'))
        except AttributeError:
            return

        try:
            external_links, internal_links, root_links, primary_links = categorize_links(the_links, url, root_url)
        except TypeError:
            return


        #change it so this depends on the input
        links_to_visit = external_links + internal_links + root_links

        #build the queue
        for link in links_to_visit:
            if link not in visited_pages and link not in visit_queue:
                visit_queue.append(link)

    visited_pages.append(url)
    count = count + 1
#    print 'number of pages visited'
#    print count

    #add pages to collected_pages depending on the criteria given if any keywords are given
    if keywords:
        page_to_add = find_pages(url, soup, keywords)

#        print 'page to add'
#        print page_to_add
        if page_to_add and page_to_add not in collected_pages:
            collected_pages.append(page_to_add)


    pics_to_add = add_pics(url, soup)
#    print 'pics to add'
#    print pics_to_add
    if pics_to_add:
        collected_pics.extend(pics_to_add)

    #here is where the actual recursion happens by finishing the queue
    while visit_queue:
        if count >= max_count:
            return

        if pic_count > pic_num:
            return

        link = visit_queue.popleft()
#        print link
        scrape_pages(link, root_url, keywords)

#    print '***done***'
    ###done with the recursive scraping function here

#here I just get a list of links from Bing, add them to the queue and go through them then reset all the global variables
def scrape_bing_src(keywords):
    visit_queue, the_url = scrape_bing.get_links(keywords, a_list = False)
    scrape_pages(visit_queue.popleft(), the_url, keywords, recurse=True)

    global collected_pics
    global pic_count
    global count
    global visited_pages
    global visit_queue

    pic_count = 0
    count = 0
    visited_pages = []
    visit_queue = deque([])

    pics_to_return = collected_pics
    collected_pics = []
    return pics_to_return
```

Here is the handler that calls the scraper function

```
#this just simply displays the images
class Try(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, keyword):
        keyword = str(keyword)
        keyword_list = keyword.split()
        img_list = scraper.scrape_bing_src(keyword_list)

        for img in img_list:
            self.response.write("""<br><img src='""" + img + """'>""")

        self.response.write('we are done here')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: great resource but it seems like there is quite a bit of information there and some of it conflicting.  Do you think it would be better to set those variables = None or to set the function that calls it outside the original class and just have it return it?

Comment: There's no two ways about it: use `keywords=None` in the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't run inside only one "server" and one instance, you probably already noticed instances tab in admin console. So there is chance that even between calls you will be switched to different server, or process will be "restarted" (more you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview)). During warmup process your application reads from disk into memory and then starts to handle requests. So every time you getting new precached python instance with its own globals variable values.

In your case it is better to use [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview).

Comment: no I don't want the global variables to stay across instances.  I suppose I just need to change it from using global though.

Comment: The global variables don't "stay" across instances. However, once your app is loaded onto an instance, the program stays running until shut down - meaning that the global variables are alive after your handler is done processing a request. Definitely sounds like you don't want global data here.